# Prove composition of two injective linear transformations is injective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I tried this:

Let $T:U\to V$ and $S:W \to U$ injective linear transformations.
Then $\ker T=0$ and $\ker S=0$.

How $S$ is injective

$S(O_w)=O_u$ and $T$ is also injective then $T(S(O_w))=O_v$

then $TS$ is injective, but I don't know if I'm right.

Comment: Actually the composition of two injective maps is always injective, regardless of whether you are working with vector spaces or not. Also, the composition of linear transformations is always another linear transformation. So you can just combine these two independent facts to conclude what you want. Now you can just prove those two simpler things.

Comment: What are $O_w$? and $O_u$?

Comment: $0_w$ is the 0 of W and $0_u$ the 0 of U

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Proceed by contradiction. What would happen if there existed a vector $\vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$ such that $S(T(\vec{v})) = \vec{0}$? Specifically, since $S(\vec{w}) = \vec{0}$ implies $\vec{w} = 0$ (as $S$ is injective), this means that $T(\vec{v}) = \vec{0}$. But since $\vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$ this means that $T$...

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to directly prove that $\text{Ker}(ST)=0$?
Take $v\in\text{Ker}(ST)$. Then $S(T(v))=0$, so $T(v)\in\text{Ker}(S)$, etc.

Comment: Also, it may be more fruitful to address why Fernando's attempt of a proof is not really a proof.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to observe that $S$ maps $0_W$ to $0_U$, and $T$ maps $0_U$ to $0_V$. Mapping $0$ to $0$ is a property that all linear maps share!

It sounds like you want to use the following property:

> A linear map $T : U \to V$ is injective if and only if $\operatorname{ker} T = \{0\}$.

Given any linear map, $\{0\} \subseteq \operatorname{ker} T$, since every linear map takes $0$ to $0$, so injectivity means that $\operatorname{ker} T \subseteq \{0\}$, or in other words, **the only vector to map to $0$ is $0$**. This is where you went wrong: you showed that $0$ is mapped to $0$ by $ST$, but you didn't show it was the **only** vector. There may be other vectors that map to $0$!

So, let's start by supposing that $w \in \operatorname{ker}(ST)$. That is, $STw = 0_V$. It is our job to show $w = 0_W$. Then, we will know that the only vector in $\operatorname{ker}(ST)$ is $0_W$, and hence $ST$ is injective.

Now, we have $0_V = STw = S(Tw)$. This means $S$ sends $Tw$ to $0_V$, so $Tw \in \operatorname{ker}(S)$. Since $T$ is injective, we have $\operatorname{ker}(S) = \{0_U\}$. Therefore, the only possible value for $Tw$ is $0_U$, and so we have $Tw = 0_U$.

Next, we do essentially the same thing. Note that $Tw = 0_U$ means $w \in \operatorname{ker} T$, and since $T$ is injective, we have $\operatorname{ker} T = \{0_W\}$. So, the only possible vector that $w$ could be is $0_W$. We have therefore proven that the only vector in $\ker(ST)$ is $\{0_W\}$, which implies $ST$ is injective, completing the proof.